# Trouble debuging with Apache 2.4.18

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I installed the new XAMPP-Environement to the latest PHP/Apache - version.
Now I have trouble debuging my framework with Codelobster witch usese the Zend-enginne.
Here short what I tested and what happens:

Under my old configuration everything worked fine:
*XAMPP 2.2.1
Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.1 
PHP 5.5.1
Codelobster 5.10.2 (here I had an older version before so perhaps it was not PHP Debugger v.5.4.0)
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
    with Codelobster PHP Debugger v5.4.0, (C) 2005-2007, by Codelobster Software*

Debuging simple-mvc-framework and single php-files could be debuged whith breakpoints.

Under my new configuration:
*XAMPP 3.2.2
Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.8 
PHP 7.0.8
Codelobster 5.10.2
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Codelobster PHP Debugger v5.4.0, (C) 2005-2007, by Codelobster Software*

single php-files can be debuged.
Frameworks as:
- simple-mvc-framework v2
- nova-framework v3
- codeigniter v3.1
can not be debuged. 
I get an timeout as soon as I activate the debugger or the Url gets changed to something like: http://www.localhost.com/codeig/ after more than 30 seconds.  Breakpoints are not hit.
I checked the php.ini for differences but did not find any.
I suspect it is as soon there is a htaccess redirecting, but these are not different from the ones I used whith my old configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!!!
Codelobster sent me a new set DLL just because of this issue :-)